# secondary tile Windows 8, blank displayname

Tags: string, windows-8, title, secondary-live-tile

I am using the secondary tile functionality to allow user to pin specific section of the app. It works as expected. But when user clicks on "pin" option, a confirmation dialog is shown. And user is provided a chance to input a new display name. It also takes a blank empty value. Is there a way I can restrict user from entering empty string (Or not allow user to pin the secondary tile without a display name)?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to enforce the displayname in Windows 8 confirmation dialg box for secondary tiles. But in Windows 10, the confirmation dialog box has been removed, so this issue should only exist on Windows 8.